# Could not determine datatype of Instant

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate with a Postgres DB and have a problem with the following query:

```
@Query("Select l from Leasing l where l.user = :user " +
        "   and (:fromDate is null or l.from >= :fromDate)")
Page<Leasing> findAllByUserAndStatusAndFromAndTo(Pageable pageable, @Param("user") User user,
                                                 @Param("fromDate") Instant from);
```

I got the error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2
```

The field is defined like this:

```
@Column(name = "from_time")
@NotNull
private Instant from;
```

I know this is a problem with Postgres, because in the test-environment an H2 database is used and it worked fine.

In the postgres database the datatype of the field is: `timestamp without time zone`

I tried to use LocalDateTime instead of Instant but it didn't work either.

**EDIT:**

If I remove `:fromDate is null` it works, but I need this check?

Comment: What data type does the column `from_time` have? `DATE`, `TIME`, `DATETIME` or anything else? Maybe it's just mixing up `from_time` (in `@Column`) and `from_date` (in `@Query`)? Those might have different types...

Comment: Add the Jadira Usertype lib as a dependency, and you'll get additional support (see dupe for more info).